# How to group similarly named elements in a list into tuples in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have read the names of all of the files in a directory in a python list like this:

```
files = ['ch1.txt', 'ch2.txt', 'ch3_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt', 'ch3_2.txt', 'ch4_1.txt']
```

What I want to do is group similar files as tuples in the list. The above example should look like

```
files_grouped = ['ch1.txt', 'ch2.txt', ('ch3_1.txt', 'ch3_2.txt'), ('ch4_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt')]
```

One way I have tried is to separate the elements I need to group from the list like so

```
groups = tuple([file for file in files if '_' in file])
single = [file for file in files if not '_' in file]
```

And I would create a new list appending the both. But how do I create the `groups` as list of tuple for `ch3` and `ch4` like `[('ch3_1.txt', 'ch3_2.txt'), ('ch4_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt')]` instead of one big tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the answers give you a generic solution that works for any kind of file names. I think you should be using regex, if you want to account for that.

```
import itertools
import re

sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: re.findall('(\d+)_(\d+)', x))    
out = [list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(sorted_files, 
                       key=lambda x: re.search('\d+', x).group() )]

print(out)
[['ch1.txt'],
 ['ch2.txt'],
 ['ch3_1.txt', 'ch3_2.txt'],
 ['ch4_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt']]
```

Note that this should work for any naming format, not just `chX_X`.

If you want your output in the exact format described, you could do a little extra post-processing:

```
out = [o[0] if len(o) == 1 else tuple(o) for o in out]
print(out)
['ch1.txt', 'ch2.txt', ('ch3_1.txt', 'ch3_2.txt'), ('ch4_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt')]
```

---

**Regex Details**

The first regex sorts by chapter section and subsection.

```
(       # first group 
\d+     # 1 or more digits
)
_       # literal underscore
(       # second group
\d+     # 1 or more digits
)
```

The second regex groups by chapter sections only - all chapters with the same section are grouped together.

Comment: thanks, I was able to adopt this solution in my code and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary (or, for simpler initialising a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

files = ['ch1.txt', 'ch2.txt', 'ch3_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt', 'ch3_2.txt', 'ch4_1.txt']

grouped = defaultdict(list)  # create an empty list for not existent entries

for f in files:
    key = f[:3]
    grouped[key].append(f)

pprint(grouped)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'ch1': ['ch1.txt'],
             'ch2': ['ch2.txt'],
             'ch3': ['ch3_1.txt', 'ch3_2.txt'],
             'ch4': ['ch4_2.txt', 'ch4_1.txt']})
```

If you want your list of tuples, you can do:

```
grouped = [tuple(l) for l in grouped.values()]
```

Which is

```
[('ch1.txt',),
 ('ch2.txt',),
 ('ch3_1.txt', 'ch3_2.txt'),
 ('ch4_2.txt', 'ch4_1.txt')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can sort the list of file name, and then use [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do this:

e.g.

```
from itertools import groupby

files = ['ch1.txt', 'ch2.txt', 'ch3_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt', 'ch3_2.txt', 'ch4_1.txt']

print([tuple(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(files),key=lambda x : x[:-4].split("_")[0])])
```

Result:

```
[('ch1.txt',), ('ch2.txt',), ('ch3_1.txt', 'ch3_2.txt'), ('ch4_1.txt', 'ch4_2.txt')]
```

Hope this helps.